# Autohide the bottom panel in gnome3 classic session

Tags: gnome, gnome-panel, gnome-shell-extension

Is there any possibility to autohide the bottom Panel in GNOME 3 classic session ?

We can autohide the top panel with this plugin : https://github.com/mlutfy/hidetopbar
But what about the bottom panel (it's the extension "Window List : https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell-extensions/-/tree/master/extensions/window-list) ?

Will you please help me.

Answer (score 0):

My answer might disappoint you, but as such, you cannot autohide the window list. This officially supported Gnome Shell extension does not support this. It would be required to adapt the source code of the extension.

As a workaround, you could achieve much of the same functionality by using [tint2](https://opensource.com/article/19/1/productivity-tool-tint2), a lightweight panel and taskbar, instead of the Window List extension. It can be set to autohide. `tint2` is available in the Ubuntu software sources, and can be installed with `sudo apt install tint2`.